# CloudKit database generates a new change token every sync - even if no changes have been made

Tags: ios, synchronization, cloudkit

My CloudKit database generates a new change token every time I ask it for changes - even if no changes have been made.

I'm happy to post code but I don't think it's pertinent to the question and I don't want to overwhelm the post. I'm posting below some console output I'm using for debugging to show that I'm saving and using the tokens, but the database is sending new ones every sync. As you can see I'm not changing anything in the database. For reference the record zone is *not* sending new tokens each time, just the database.

Is this expected behavior? If not, any thoughts on why/how this is happening?

```
 SyncOperation fires on Simulator, Private 
☣️ FetchDatabaseChangesOperation fires 
☣️ FetchDatabaseChangesOperation changeTokenUpdatedBlock
☣️ token used: <CKServerChangeToken: 0x7b04000029f0; data=AQAAAWpzvY7V>
☣️ server says: <CKServerChangeToken: 0x7b0400025330; data=AQAAAWpzvoVX>
☣️ saving token: <CKServerChangeToken: 0x7b0400001130; data=AQAAAWpzvoVX>
☣️ FetchDatabaseChangesOperation complete  ⏱0.26
 FetchRecordZoneChangesOperation no changes 
 ModifyObjectsOperation - no changes 
 UploadChangesOperation - no uploads 
 ModifyObjectsOperation - no changes 
 SyncOperation complete  ⏱0.28

☁️  Pull to refresh fires

 SyncOperation fires on Simulator, Private 
☣️ FetchDatabaseChangesOperation fires 
☣️ FetchDatabaseChangesOperation changeTokenUpdatedBlock
☣️ token used: <CKServerChangeToken: 0x7b0400001f50; data=AQAAAWpzvoVX>
☣️ server says: <CKServerChangeToken: 0x7b0400001e90; data=AQAAAWpzvopq>
☣️ saving token: <CKServerChangeToken: 0x7b0400025350; data=AQAAAWpzvopq>
☣️ FetchDatabaseChangesOperation complete  ⏱0.24
 FetchRecordZoneChangesOperation no changes 
 ModifyObjectsOperation - no changes 
 UploadChangesOperation - no uploads 
 ModifyObjectsOperation - no changes 
 SyncOperation complete  ⏱0.25

☁️  Pull to refresh fires

 SyncOperation fires on Simulator, Private 
☣️ FetchDatabaseChangesOperation fires 
☣️ FetchDatabaseChangesOperation changeTokenUpdatedBlock
☣️ token used: <CKServerChangeToken: 0x7b0400001f50; data=AQAAAWpzvopq>
☣️ server says: <CKServerChangeToken: 0x7b0400000d00; data=AQAAAWpzvo3P>
☣️ saving token: <CKServerChangeToken: 0x7b0400026840; data=AQAAAWpzvo3P>
☣️ FetchDatabaseChangesOperation complete  ⏱0.13
 FetchRecordZoneChangesOperation no changes 
 ModifyObjectsOperation - no changes 
 UploadChangesOperation - no uploads 
 ModifyObjectsOperation - no changes 
 SyncOperation complete  ⏱0.13
```

**EDIT TO ADD:**

If I go to the dashboard and fetch zone changes since *any* of these change tokens, it gives me the correct response that there are no changes:

[image: iCloud Dashboard showing no changes occured]

I don't understand why it generates new tokens if there are no new changes?

Comment: How do you get nice debug output like that?

Comment: I've got my code riddled with print statements... I spent so much time debugging my cloudkit stuff it seemed like it was worth it

Comment: Do you have some kind of printer helper function or library that you can share? I run into the same problems all the time

Comment: I don't - it's just my own code.  I've got a configuration file - just a struct, that has a static let logCKController: Bool, and throughout my CloudKit code I just have a bunch of if Configuration.logCKController { print "stuff" } statements...

Answer (score 0):

I, too, noticed this. It seems as though `CKDatabase` treats any fetch operations as a database activity worthy of vending a new token. This should be fine as it shouldn't cause any side effects in your app. Just a matter of ensuring the latest token gets persisted locally even if there aren't any change.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation? I used CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation instead to recognize the change and get the changed records only.